# Wordpress plugin - find where a data field is stored in the database

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I want to mass edit a data field that a plugin in WordPress stores (one per post). (It's the media file reference in the Blubrry plugin). How can I find the field in PhpMyAdmin? Ideally I'd like to be able to open the table and copy down a value.

Comment: Many thanks for this Angelo

I want to change http://mediaurl.mp3

to http://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/http://mediaurl.mp3

en masse. Is this suitable for that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool built into the Blubrry PowerPress plugin that allows you to modify the media URLs, Assuming you want to modify the values, this option may be ideal. First make sure you are in "Advanced mode" in PowerPress. Then go PowerPress settings, the menu on the left will expand with additional sub menu options. select "Tools" under the PowerPress submenu. In the PowerPress Tools section there is a resource called "Find and Replace Media URLs", select this to use the built-in find and replace tool. The find replace tool can use regular expressions or exact partial URL matching and provides a prewview before you make final changes as well as an option to verify the new URL before making the database change. This is useful for converting URLs from http:// to https:// or when switching media hosting companies.

As for phpMyAdmin fields, that will depend if you are using Post Type podcasting or Podcast Channels. Assuming you are not using either of those features, the database records you are looking for will have the meta_key name "enclosure" found in the wp_postmeta table. If you are using podcast channels or post type podcasting, the custom field name will start with _enclosure: the data following the colon is specific to each post type or channel. When querying the database for these custom fields you can do WHERE meta_key LIKE '%enclosure%'.

One warning, the value of the enclosure is formatted in a special way. There are 4 lines of data, the first being the media URL, 2nd line the file size and the 3rd the content type. The 4th line is a PHP serialized value of all other settings associated with the episode data. This was a standard that was set back in 2007 by another podcasting plugin at the time (has since disappeared). The first 3 lines are required for WordPress itself. WordPress ignores the 4th line which is why it was an ideal solution at the time, and still works today.

If you have any questions please feel free to contact me or reply to this comment. Full disclosure, I am the lead developer of the Blubrry PowerPress plugin.

Comment: Many thanks for this Angelo I want to change mediaurl.mp3 to dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/http://mediaurl.mp3 en masse. Is this suitable for that?